Optimizer ExpressionJoiner Help
Hi im a newbie learning about Optimizer and Im trying to Join a function like this
      function fun_trigger_61() -> vloc
        {
            let ret := vloc
            ret := vloc
            vloc := vloc
            let expr := fun_return_2_20()
            vloc := fun_multiply_48(expr, fun_return_1_12())
        }

I want to change it into something of the form
   function fun_trigger_61() -> vloc
        {
            vloc := fun_multiply_48(fun_return_2_20(), fun_return_1_12())
        }

This is the Code i used
pragma solidity 0.6.9;

contract C {

    uint x=1;
    function return_1() public  returns (uint){
        return x;
    }
    function return_2() public pure returns (uint) {
        return 2;
    }

    function add(uint x, uint y) public returns (uint){
        return x+y;
    }
    function multiply(uint x, uint y) public returns (uint){
        return x*y;
    }


    function trigger() public returns (uint) {
        return multiply(return_2(),return_1());
    }
}

and the solc optimizer sequence i used
solc test.sol --optimize --ir-optimized --yul-optimizations "j url [ji]"
I want to do this without inline assembly
Thank You
